# "Is owned programmers" - What does this mean?

Tags: comprehension, error

Example with a context ([How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)):

> The doc comments for the Java platform API specification **is owned programmers**. However, they are edited by both programmers and writers. It is a basic premise that writers and programmers honor each other's capabilities and both contribute to the best doc comments possible.

I completely don't understand what that sentence is trying to say. What do they mean by *is owned programmers*?

Comment: I believe it's a grammatical mistake.  They omitted a word.  The doc comments are owned **by** programmers, however, writers also contribute to them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems a grammatical mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its current form it doesn't make any sense - it's a grammar mistake. They most likely missed out the word "by".

> The doc comments for the Java platform API specification is owned **by** programmers.